# Loading ROM bootloader in qemu

Tags: qemu

I have a custom bootloader, I have the entry point of the bootloader, How do I specify this address to qemu?

I also have this warning when I try to load the image with this line `qemu-system-mips  -pflash img_`:

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'img_' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

I tried `-pflash=img_,format=raw` but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should perform some dig into [qemu sources](https://github.com/qemu/qemu) to play with custom bootloader images at qemu. QEMU loads booloader at *board initilizaton function*, which is board specific.

Run following to view all available MIPS board models:

```
qemu-system-mips64 -machine  ?
Supported machines are:
magnum               MIPS Magnum
malta                MIPS Malta Core LV (default)
mips                 mips r4k platform
mipssim              MIPS MIPSsim platform
none                 empty machine
pica61               Acer Pica 61
```

This models are implemented in *qemu/hw/mips/* files. (look for * *_init* funtctions)

For example, for *malta* board (which is default) it is *hw/mips/mips_malta.c*. Look at *mips_malta_init* function: it constructs devices, buses and cpu, register memory regions and place bootloader to memory. Seems that *FLASH_ADDRESS* macro is that you looking for.

Note that this init functions is common thing to all boards that QEMU implements.
Also every board have some reference/datasheet document, and QEMU model should complement with them, as a programer view.